# removing default syntax in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, syntax, default

In visual studio if I would double click to put a label on the screen the default code is .

```
    <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

However, I do not want the vertical alignment and horizontal alignment to come as default text when I put it on the screen. The reason for this is because I have made a style sheet and if I put the label on the screen with a style of HorizontalAlignment="Right" instead of HorizontalAlignment="Left" I have to get rid of the original default for it to use that style. Does anyone know how to remove the default syntax. When I put a label on the screen I just want it to say

```
    <Label/>
```

Comment: On the whole, it's faster to just type <Label/> than it is to go hunting and pecking through menus looking for icons of controls.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but you can get around it by resetting the element properties.

You can manually reset the layout by right click the element in the the designer pane.

1. Right click the element
2. Select "Reset Layout"
3. Select "All"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The control's DefaultInitializer determines its default values when dragged in from the toolbox:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.model.defaultinitializer.aspx .

The control's default values can be overridden but, as far as I can establish, *can't be removed*.

```
[Feature(typeof(LabelDefaults))]
public class DemoLabel : Label{}

class LabelDefaults : DefaultInitializer
{
    public override void InitializeDefaults(ModelItem item)
    {
        item.Properties["HorizontalAlignment"].SetValue("Right");
        item.Properties["VerticalAlignment"].SetValue("Bottom");
        item.Properties["Content"].SetValue("Blahblahblah");
    }
}
```

I think you're stuck with the default values.